# how to get minutes difference?

Tags: t-sql, sybase

with t-sql, I try to get time difference for running a sql statement:

```
declare @t1 datetime
declare @t2 datetime
declare @msg varchar(12)

set @t1 = getdate()
--run sql statements
....
set @t2 = getdate()

set @msg = Convert(varchar(12), Datediff(minute, @t1, @t2))
Print 'Processing time is %1!' , @msg
```

sql statement take time more than 1 munite, but output from print said time is 0.

How to get time difference? or how can get time difference with minutes + seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datediff returns the number of "boundaries" crossed between two datetimes (i.e. it returns an integer).  If your start and end time are greater than 1 minute apart but less than 2 minutes apart, Datediff(minute, start, end) will return 1 since there isn't a full 2 minutes between them.  What you need to do is get the number of seconds between the two datetimes, and then compute the number of minutes.

```
declare @t1 datetime
declare @t2 datetime
declare @seconds int

set @t1 = getdate()
--run sql statements
--....
set @t2 = getdate()

set @seconds = Datediff(S, @t1, @t2)
Print 'Processing time is ' + 
       convert(varchar, @seconds/60) + ':' + 
       convert(varchar, @seconds % 60)
```

I'm using `@seconds/60` to get the number of whole minutes, and `@seconds % 60` to get the remaining number of seconds.  If you need more precision, you can do the same sort of thing with milliseconds.